# Questions about polynomial algbras

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, machine-learning

If $x$ is vector of dimension 3, say $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$, then $S^d$ is an operator such that
$$ S^d(x)=\left(
 \begin{matrix}
   x_2 & x_1 & 0 &0 & 0&  ...& 0 &0&0\\
   x_3 & x_2 & x_1 & 0 & 0& ...& 0 &0&0\\
   0 & x_3 & x_2 & x_1& 0 &...& 0 &0&0\\
   0 & 0 & x_3 & x_2& x_1 &...& 0 &0&0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_3& x_2 &...& 0 &0&0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& x_3 &...& 0 &0&0\\
 ...&...&...&...&...&...&...&...&...\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 &...& x_3 &x_2&x_1\\  
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 &...& 0 &x_3&x_2\\ 
  \end{matrix}
  \right) $$
The matrix $S^d(x)$ is $d \times d$ matrix $(d>3)$
where $S^d_{ij}=x_{i-j+2}$ if $0<(i-j+2)<4$ and $S^d_{ij}=0$ otherwise.
My question is for any given $d \times d$ matrix A, can I find a finite sequence  $\{x^i\}_{i=1}^N$ where $x^i$ is a vector of dimension 3, such that
$$A=S^d(x^1)\times S^d(x^2)\times ...\times S^d(x^N) $$\
And if could, please provide some bound of N. \
Actually, this is related to the convolution neural network and I am trying to prove that the fully connected network belongs to the convolution neural network.

Comment: Counting the variables shows that this leads to under/overdetermined systems unless $3N=d^2$, so $d=3n$ and $N=3n^2$. Since $d>3$, $N\ge12$. For $n=1$ I can find counterexamples, but not in the mood to check for $N=12$ and $36$ variables.